# how to stop toggling visibility of div on check box click event in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am using JQuery 1.7.1 I want to make div containing check box blink on button click event. I have written following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var nIntervId;

    function changeColor() {
        nIntervId = setInterval(flashText, 500);
    }

    function flashText() {
        var oElem = document.getElementById("divchkBox");
        oElem.style.visibility = oElem.style.visibility == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible";
    }

    function stopTextColor() {
        clearInterval(nIntervId);
    }
    </script>
    <div id="divchkBox">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" runat="server" Text="hi" />
    </div>
<asp:Button ID="start" Text="start" runat="server" OnClientClick="changeColor();" />
```

Now, I would like to stop this blinking effect till mouse is over particularly blinking check box and/or that particular check box click event. How do I achieve that?

Also is it possible to send the id of the checkbox div inside the changecolor() or flashText() instead of the hard-coded value?

Thank you.

Comment: @Ross : I believe you did not understand my requirement correctly. It is as follows :
1. On button click event checkbox div will start blinking.
2. Once it starts blinking, then only, on mouse over and/or checkbox checked even, I want it to stop blinking. And I want to pass the id of the element to changecolor() or flashtext() as parameter so that I can use this feature to any other elemets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your problem, you want the div box to start blinking when you click on the button

```
//declare variables
var containerDiv = jQuery('div#divchkBox'),
    chkbox = jQuery('#chkBox'),
    intervalTime = 500,
    nIntervId ;

//when user clicks on button
jQuery('#start').click(function(){
  nIntervId = setInterval(flashText,intervalTime);
});

//show/hide div
function flashText(){
  containerDiv.fadeToggle(intervalTime);
}
```

You can specify a speed in fadeToggle in milliseconds. I have set it to the same interval as the toggle time. This *should* give a smooth fade in/out effect.

You have not supplied the code for `changecolor()`, but here is how to stop the flashing and pass the id of the checkbox when you hover over the checkbox:

```
chkbox.hover(function(){
  removeInterval(nIntervId); //stop fade toggle
  containerDiv.stop().show(); //stop any fading animations and show the containing box
  changecolor($(this).attr('id')); //pass the id of this checkbox to changecolor function
  // ... or
  //changecolor($(this)); //just pass in the checkbox object so you don't have to do a dom lookup again.
});
```

Edit:

To make the button target the div, you will need to pass in the id of the div in the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="start" Text="start" runat="server" OnClientClick="changeColor();" data-target-div="divchkBox"/>
```

We then add an anonymous function in the click event to pass our div id to the flashText function:

```
//when user clicks on button
jQuery('#start').click(function(){
  nIntervId = setInterval(
      function() {
          flashText( jQuery(this).attr('data-target-div') );
      },
      intervalTime
  );
});
```

We alter the flashText function:

```
//show/hide div
function flashText(id){
  jQuery('#' + id).fadeToggle(intervalTime);
}
```

Now we alter the checkbox on click event:

```
jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').hover(function(){
  removeInterval(nIntervId); //stop fade toggle
  $(this).parent().stop().show(); //stop any fading animations and show the containing box
});
```

And, finally, we remove the two defunct variables from the top of our script:

```
//declard variables. We have removed containerDiv and chkbox
var intervalTime = 500,
    nIntervId ;
```

This approach is not very efficient as we are doing a dom lookup every time fadeText runs (twice a second for one element). This can be refactored to retrieve the element from an object of elements but this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoul'd do something like this: [exemple](http://jsbin.com/uyuner/17/edit)

In short you make a method that select an element from a provided selector (parameter) and uses setInterval and jQuery.toggle() methods to obtain blink effect.
This method have to keep setInterval handler for futures blink pauses.

After what you should use jQuery event mechanism to pilot the blink effect.

Comment: Thanks yours and Richard Parnaby-King's way is same just conventions are different... and it works splendidlly.